# How to make diamond pattern using java?

Tags: java, loops

How to make this pattern
if input N = 5
Output :
[image: diamond]

Mine is like this, it become 2N
if input N = 5
Output
[image: my diamond]

Here's my code

```
int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for(j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    for(i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for(j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

What should i fix??

Comment: Yeah sure it goes to 2N. Look at the 2nd for-loop:
 for(j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++)
2*i - 1 does exactly what it shall - running to 2N-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running these two loops from `0` to `N` twice. Just run half `N/2` in each loop.

Example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (n / 2 + 1); i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) System.out.print(" ");
      for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) System.out.print("*");
      System.out.print("\n");
    }

    // N/2
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) System.out.print(" ");
      for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) System.out.print("*");
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check odd numbers in your loop. Please see the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printPattern(5);
  }

  private static void printPattern(int n) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      if (i % 2 != 0) {
        for (j = 1; j <= (n - i)/2; j++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      if (i % 2 != 0) {
        for (j = 1; j <= (n - i)/2; j++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (j = 0; j <i; j++) {
          System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
 }
```